# What happens to memory when removing view from view controller without release?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

If I remove the only view from the view controller: `[myViewController.view removeFromSuperview]` without `[myViewController release]`.  Will the memory be freed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Unless you wrote autorelease when you allocated, or release'd after you added it.

Comment: And then it would be dealloced almost immediately, which isn't very useful.

Comment: No it wouldn't. When you add a subview to a view, it gets retained.

Comment: Your answer assumes that there's another reference to, and retain on, the view in user523234's code. The usual practice is to create the subview by whatever means, add it to its superview, and _not_ keep a claim on it, so I don't understand where that assumption comes from. In other words, since the circumstances you put after "Unless" are the expected ones, it doesn't make sense to answer "No."

Comment: @Josh: Yeah, the 'Unless' circumstances are the usual way of doing things, but removeFromSuperview doesn't directly cause memory to be freed. It may, if you did things 'the usual way', but maybe you didn't for whatever reason (or maybe you don't know the usual way), in which case it won't. For example, I'm not sure if tc knows 'the usual way', since s/he wrote that the view would be dealloced almost immediately, which isn't true if you add it to a view as a subview, as it then gets retained.:

Comment: I interpreted "it" as the VC. The VC retains the view (until it receives a memory warning when the view has no superview). The question doesn't specify what retains the VC, but if you (auto)release after adding the view to the hierarchy, then it gets dealloced "almost" immediately, which is rather useless.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's `UIView` documentation for `-removeFromSuperview`:

> [If the receiver’s superview is not
>   nil](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), the superview releases the
>   receiver. If you plan to reuse a view,
>   be sure to retain it before calling
>   this method and release it again later
>   as appropriate.